# nginx mod_redirect if first part of uri is not a file

Tags: nginx, php, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-16.04

I'm migrating from Apache to Nginx server and trying to figure out how to replace my `.htaccess` with nginx config.

In my rewrite I want to enable pretty links and need the server to check if the first part is not a file then redirect to `index.php` otherwise redirect to that file.

Example:

I have two PHP files in the root directory: `index.php` and `files.php`.

```
https://example.com/token/login ---> index.php/token/login
https://example.com/index.php/token/login ---> index.php/token/login //same as above

https://example.com/files.php/token/login ---> files.php/token/login
```

My current /default file is

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name vpn.simpleinformatics.com www.vpn.simpleinformatics.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-vpn.simpleinformatics.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name vpn.simpleinformatics.com;

    location / {
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
    }
}
```

This redirects all requests to `index.php`, even `files.php/etc..` requests :(.

So how can I tell nginx to check if the first part of URI is a file, then do the redirect to that file.

Comment: Your `location ~ \.php$` rule does not match PHP URIs containing PATH INFO. See [this article](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) for more.

Comment: @RichardSmith i have read it,, still no clue how to do it !